# Sign files with a private key in a store with password as parameter

Tags: batch-file, code-signing, signtool

I can (Authenticode) sign files with a batch file. Everything works fine. The private key is stored in the user store. 
Since we implemented double signing with sha1 and sha256, we need to enter the password twice during the process, once for each hash. I wanted to rewrite the batch so we only have to enter the password once and it will be used as the parameter for the two signing steps. I did so by adding the `/p` Parameter - but this one only works with certificates stored in `.pfx` files:

> `SignTool Error: The /p option requires the /f option.`

Do I need to work with pfx files or is there a way to use passwords for private keys in the user store?

I thought that keeping the key in the store would be more secure (I'm actually not sure about that) - Am I right with that? If no, why would I even keep private keys in there?

Here's the example batch file - the /p option does not work

```
REM @echo off
set /p SoftwareName=Enter Software Name:
set /p SignPass=Enter Certificate Password:
echo %SoftwareName%

CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86

REM SHA1 signature
signtool sign /v /sha1 <certhash> /n "CompanyName" /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll /p %SignPass% /d "%SoftwareName%" %1 
REM SHA256 signature added for security reasons
signtool sign /v /sha1 <certhash> /fd sha256 /n "CompanyName" /tr http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp /td sha256 /as /p %SignPass% /d "%SoftwareName%" %1
```